"This argument has been moved away from."
is this a well-formed, idiomatic sentence?
Can this sentence be improved to avoid awkwardness?
The meaning should be "people used to make a particular argument on a topic, but they no longer make that argument."

What is it supposed to mean? When do you imagine it being used? Do you mean that nobody is arguing about this topic any more, or some other meaning? It's grammatical but it's an odd thing to say.

That's an editing question and not usually allowed.

@stuartf "people used to make a particular argument on a topic, but they no longer make that argument. "

I took the liberty of adding your comment to the question itself. You can do that yourself in the future using the "Edit" button below the question.

Something like "We've since moved on"


There's nothing grammatically wrong with this sentence.
For this particular situation, no, it's not very idiomatic. This might be from a combination of the passive voice and the preposition. After all, "This argument has been abandoned" uses the passive voice and is much more idiomatic. I'm trying to imagine some other situation where a similar construction might feel less awkward. I'm imagining people running a survey, saying "Only twenty questions have been responded to." This is still not very natural, and would likely be replaced by something like "only twenty questions have gotten responses."
But that points to the fact that "move away from" isn't the most common phrase choice for this idea. It's also very uncommon, for any of its meanings, to be found in the passive voice ("Their house has been moved away from," "When I farted I was moved away from by everybody"). There might be better choices for the idea that "no one makes this argument anymore." Personally, I like exactly that, or something like it: "Few people make this argument anymore." Direct and clear.


Or if you want to keep "this argument" as the subject: "This argument has been abandoned."

I wouldn't particularly say the sentence in question is idiomatic but I agree it sounds awkward, while grammatically correct. I would say something like "We've moved away from this argument". Generally in English people don't really use the passive a lot.
